# Both Singleton implementations equally Multi Threading proof?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

There are two Implementations of a Singleton in the code snippets beneath.
Are they both proper ways to implement Singletons in a multi threaded environment in Java?

If so, does that mean the second way of implementation is completely useless, and **whenever you want to implement a Singleton, just use the enum-way?**

My preffered way of writing a Singleton:

```
public enum Singleton {
  INSTANCE();
}
```

Another way of writing a Singleton (explicitly synchronized):

```
public class Singleton {

  private static Singleton instance = null;
  private Singleton() {}

  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instanz == null) {
      instanz = new Singleton();
    }
    return instanz;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why some programmers discuss about the ways of how to create singletons, is that they want support for lazy creation but worry about the performance of subsequent invocations of the accessor method.

So your class using `synchronized` fulfills the lazy creation aspect, but subsequent invocations may suffer from the then-unnecessary overhead of `synchronized`. To overcome that hypothetical overhead, the infamous double-checked locking was invented, which caused even more discussions about this “problem” which is actually completely irrelevant:

If you want to combine lazy creation with a singleton, you may just use:

```
public class Singleton {
    static final Singleton INSTANCE=new Singleton();
    private Singleton(){}
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

The whole construct is lazy as the class initialization won’t happen before the first thread calls `getInstance()` and it’s thread-safe, because the class initialization itself is guaranteed to be thread-safe by the JVM. And it’s the most efficient solution as subsequent invocations will just read a `final` field without the need for synchronizations.

This is exactly what happens as well when using

```
public enum Singleton {
  INSTANCE;
}
```

It saves you from declaring a `private` constructor as the compiler does that for you. And the field is implicitly `static final`. One difference is that the field itself is exposed and no accessor method required.

Also, `enum`s support Serialization, intrinsically. When the constant is stored, no instance data gets stored, only the type and constant name. And upon deserialization, the current runtime instance will be looked up. So if you need Serialization support, `enum` should be preferred, otherwise there is not much difference (using an `enum` saves some typing).

But

- How often do you need a singleton in your application? (If you say “often”, you should rethink your software design)
- How often is the performance of the accessor method of a singleton relevant in your application?
- How often does the laziness of a singleton instance creation matter?
- If you ever need a singleton, how often do you really need an “iron-hard” guaranty about the singleton property? I.e., if someone manages to create a second instance using dirty Reflection tricks, the problems which might arise then are *his* problems, aren’t they?

Simply said, the Singleton Design Pattern seems to be heavily overrated and discussions about how to implement it efficiently even more…

Comment: I think your answer is  good, but unfortunately provides too much irrelevant information in the end... Whether or not the Singleton should be considered to be an "anti-pattern" is a totally different cup of tea. Especially your last "to-sum-it-all-up" phrase is not related to my question at all.

Anyway, there are rare situations where the Singleton pattern is the single and best way of reaching a certain aim.

Comment: I’m not saying that you don’t need the Singleton pattern. I’m saying that its use is rare enough that you don’t need to care about the performance impact of using `synchronized`, for example. So you can use the second code example of your question without hesitation. I’m also saying that you don’t need to compare how hard the guarantees made by using `enum` or an ordinary singleton class are, for example. In practice, the differences between the approaches are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You both approaches looks fine. However for creating Singleton I will suggest below approach which is 100% thread safe and no synchronization issue because **it leverages Java's class loading mechanism.**

*P.S.: Credits to @james for the trigger.*

**Lazy singleton:**
Like this class Provider will be loaded only once and hence only one instance of Network class will exist, and no two threads can create 2 instances in same JVM because class will not be loaded twice.

Advantages:

- Instance is created only when it is needed.
- No need to bear the cost of synchronization when calling `getInstance()`, which will happen when there is `getInstance()` with synchronization.
- There can be other static methods in the class which can be called without creating an instance, and create an instance only when instance method invocation is needed. This is a good advantage of lazy singleton.

  ```
  public class Network {
  private Network(){

  }

  private static class Provider {
      static final Network INSTANCE = new Network();
  }

  public static Network getInstance() {
      return Provider.INSTANCE;
  }
  //More code...
  ```

  }

**Eager singleton:**

```
private static Network INSTANCE = null;

private Network(){
}

static {
    INSTANCE = new Network();
}

public static Network getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

**In the end:** You have got it right that 2nd approach you specified is really the last pick, because it has to bear the cost of synchronization each time 2 threads are trying to get the instance of the singleton.

Now, its game of ENUM singletons v/s lazy singletons. I have provided you few links about why folks don't prefer ENUM for singleton and also the scalability of ENUM singletons v/s lazy singletons based on class loading.

Both approaches will work seamlessly, so its matter of choice, hence true answer is "It depends!!!" :)

Comment: So what makes this better/different from the enum-way, other than requiring more code for its implementation?

Comment: You can find a lot of blogs and discussions. Few are - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/what-are-the-downsides-of-implementing-a-singleton-with-javas-enum and http://closingbraces.net/2011/07/04/enum-as-singleton/

Comment: Class loading approach is very straight forward, easy to understand by dev, and reliable .. It is guaranteed to work and will work, until JVM starts loading same class 2 time, which is really not at all likely ..

Comment: Enum approach implements the singleton by taking advantage of Java's guarantee that any enum value is instantiated only once in a Java program. Now if you want to compare which is more unlikely to change in future release - enum value being instantiated only once OR class being loaded only once? *(however either is very unlikely but I want to put the odds)* So, I think class loading is more scalable.

Comment: There is no need for that inner class. Just declare the `static final` field within `Network` and it all works the same.

Comment: @Holger Yes, agree but in that case there would be need of an external class named `Provider`. So, inner class best suits the requirement here.

Comment: Why do you need a class named “Provider”? Class names have no special semantic in Java. You don’t need a class named “Provider”, not as an inner class and not as an external class.

Comment: But that's the leverage for class loading.

Comment: What do you mean by “leverage for class loading”? That phrase does not transport any information. There is no difference between how class loading works for the `Network` class and how it works for the `Provider` class. You don’t need two classes here.

Comment: @Jan Hagrawal's example has a name.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom  It was an elegant solution, invented at a time when enums had not yet been introduced into Java, and the Java memory model had some loopholes in it that meant double-checked locking did not necessarily work.

Comment: @Holger James have said it all. Based on his inputs, I have explicated my answer for lazy v/s eager singleton.

Comment: @james large: the fact that it has a name doesn’t change the other fact that it is obsolete in most cases. “double checked locking” also has a name. As said, the initialization of the outer class is as lazy as that of the inner class. So the holder class is only needed when there ought to be a difference between these two initialization times, e.g. when you control *multiple* resources. For a *singleton* this is not the case. The reason why an `enum` *without* an inner class can replace that pattern for a singleton is exactly because that `enum` class is initialized as lazy as any other class.

Comment: @Holger I cannot agree *"initialization of the outer class is as lazy as that of the inner class"*. If some static method of the outer class needs to be accessed first before an instance is needed then outer class needs to be initialized, so inner class is at one degree higher lazy initialization then outer class. This link - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/what-are-the-downsides-of-implementing-a-singleton-with-javas-enum very well discuss the bad's about Enum as singleton. Yes, class loading based lazy singleton can be old approach, but sometimes "Old is Gold".

Comment: *"The reason why an enum without an inner class can replace that pattern for a singleton is exactly because that enum class is initialized as lazy as any other class."* Enum cannot replace singletons just because they can be initialized as lazily has another class, there should be some good reason. Implicit serialization you mentioned can be an advantage but it can produce some really hard to bugs. Of course everything has pros and cons/

Comment: @hagrawal: `static` methods contradict the purpose of a singleton *instance*. Nevertheless, if you have both in a class, using a nested class has a point. But since the example here has no such `static` method, using an additional class just raises the overhead without any advantage. If you recommend using a nested class, even when there is no advantage in the code as-is, you should make clear, why. Just consider that the reader, including the OP, might not be aware of when it makes a difference and when not.

Comment: Btw, as said in my answer, I doubt that these differences are ever relevant in real-life code. Granted, there is the hypothetical scenario that you call a `static` method of a singleton class without needing the singleton instance itself, or needing it significantly later. But even then, it’s only relevant if you combine it with the other hypothetical scenario that the initialization is so costly that you will notice. When, ever, did you encounter that in real life?

Comment: @Holger I had mentioned static method point in the last "Advantages" bullet and `//More code...` in the code snippet, per se. Having said, sure, I will try to make more explicit reference in future.

Comment: @Holger No, in my app, we really don't have singletons itself because we don't need any global state, we have many static classes which are serving as utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

Both are thread safe but the first one, using an enum, avoids unnecessary locking and is preferable in most situations.

Comment: could you define situations where it is not preferable to use an enum?

Comment: In the rare case where you don't want the singleton to be loaded when the class is first used you can use the static singleton holder pattern (also called initialisation on demand). But that's probably only necessary in 1% of the situations where you need a singleton. In the other 99% of situations an enum is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution fits when you create a singelton because you want to model a single instance of something. In this solution if an Exception happens during creation of the instance like file not found, you will get a classnotfound exception.

The second solution fits when you create a singelton because the creation of the object takes very long and it involves access to the file system or network.